# Update current page from widget method outside the stateful class

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a method outside the stateful class for showing a dialog I want to refresh the data on the page after I close the dialog how it can be one? If I push the Screen again it will act weird (it will open the home page then go to the current page any idea of that it may help me to fix my issue.

```
    AlertWidget(BuildContext context, String Fname, String Lname, String key) {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _firstName = TextEditingController(text: Fname);
  final TextEditingController _lastName = TextEditingController(text: Lname);
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      var _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      var _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      return Center(
        child: Material(
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                height: _height - _height * 11.5 / 16,
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Align(
                          alignment: (translator.currentLanguage == "en")
                              ? Alignment.topLeft
                              : Alignment.topRight,
                          child: Text(
                            translator.translate('Name'),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: ProjectTheme.projectPrimaryColor,
                                fontSize: 25),
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: displayHeight(context) * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("${translator.translate('FirstName')}:",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: _height * .8 / 16,
                            width: _width * 1.5 / 16,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: _height * .5 / 16,
                            width: _width * 5.5 / 16,
                            child: Container(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _firstName,
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value.trim().isEmpty)
                                      return 'This field is required.';
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
                                    spreadRadius: 2,
                                    blurRadius: 5,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 1),
                                  ),
                                ],
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("${translator.translate('LastName')}:",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: _height * 1 / 16,
                            width: _width * 1.5 / 16,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: _height * .5 / 16,
                            width: _width * 5.5 / 16,
                            child: Container(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _lastName,
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value.trim().isEmpty)
                                      return 'This field is required.';
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
                                    spreadRadius: 2,
                                    blurRadius: 5,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 1),
                                  ),
                                ],
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: _height * .3 / 16),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 35,
                          width: 100,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: ProjectTheme.projectPrimaryColor,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                spreadRadius: 2,
                                blurRadius: 10,
                                offset: Offset(0, 3),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                bool isChanged = !(_firstName.text == Fname &&
                                    _lastName == Lname);
                                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth =
                                      FirebaseAuth.instance;
                                  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection('users')
                                      .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid)
                                      .update((key == 'name')
                                          ? {
                                              'firstName':
                                                  _firstName.text.trim(),
                                              'lastName': _lastName.text.trim(),
                                              'fullName':
                                                  _firstName.text.trim() +
                                                      ' ' +
                                                      _lastName.text.trim(),
                                              'userName':
                                                  _firstName.text.trim() +
                                                      ' ' +
                                                      _lastName.text.trim(),
                                            }
                                          : {
                                              key: _firstName.text.trim() +
                                                  ' ' +
                                                  _lastName.text.trim()
                                            });

                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection('users')
                                      .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid)
                                      .get()
                                      .then((value) {
                                    UserData newUser = UserData(
                                      .......
                                    );
                                    Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false)
                                        .updateUser(newUser);
                                    // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                                    //     MaterialPageRoute(
                                    //         builder: (ctx) => profileScreen()));
                                  });
                                  
                                }
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                translator.translate('Save'),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Sorry for the long code, I'm trying to get much info as I can if you need more let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can define a method from the `Stateful Widget` that executes `setState()` method to refresh and hand it over to `AlertWidget`.
As you can see in the definition of `showDialog` it is an asynchronus method that is done when you close the dialog. So try using `then()` method of `Future` to execute the method handed over from the `Stateful Widget` when you close the dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `showDialog` function, returns a future that can be used to see when the dialog is closed. Return this future to the page and `await` it or call `then` on it to know when it is done.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> AlertWidget(
  BuildContext context,
  String Fname,
  String Lname,
  String key,
) {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _firstName = TextEditingController(text: Fname);
  final TextEditingController _lastName = TextEditingController(text: Lname);
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        /*...*/
      });
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {

  // this function opens the alert dialog & calls setState when the dialog is closed
  void showDialogOnTap() {
    // show dialog
    AlertWidget(context, 'Fname', 'Lname', 'Pkey')
        .then((_) { // then on closed
      setState(() {}); // set page state
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: showDialogOnTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```